# make a for loop update twice

Tags: loops, for-loop

i want to print out the four chinese letters over and over again one at a time

package matrixArrayLoop;

public class MatrixArrayLoop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] kai = {'开', '凯', '開', '楷'};
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<kai.length;i++)
        System.out.println(kai[i]);
    if(i==kai.length)
        i=0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i used a while loop with an if and bracketed them so they would run

```
char[] kai = {'开', '凯', '開', '楷'};
    int i=0;
    while(i<=kai.length) {{{
        System.out.println(kai[i]);}
    i++;}
    if(i==kai.length)
    i=0;}
```